# Как в функции Python извне изменить переменную?

Tags: python, область-видимости

При написании скрипта расчета интеграла функции методом Гаусса мне необходимо достигнуть требуемой точности расчета `delta`. Она зависит от параметра `j_els`. Если точность не удовлетворяет заданной (ошибку видим по переменной `err_gauss`), то параметр надо удвоить и снова выполнить расчет интеграла в рамках внутренней функции `gauss()`. Если опять не удовлетворяет, параметр `j_els` снова удваивается и так - до достижения требуемой точности либо показателя `max_iter` (максимальное число итераций).

Причем запрашиваемый у пользователя порядок интегрирования `n` не может быть больше шести. Порядок используется при расчете первоначального `j_els`. Реализация функции `gauss_integrated(a, b)` такова, что `n` необходимо запрашивать.

Пытаясь это реализовать, написал пункт 9, где в цикле while  пытаюсь достигнуть требуемой точности. Однако я не знаю, как передать в функцию `gauss()` переменную `j_els` с удвоенным значением, ведь она не является аргументом функции. Как исправить код? Не стал приводить скрипт полностью, а лишь - опорные его пункты. Девятый пункт кода, при этом, показал в полном виде.

```
import numpy as np

def func_for_integrate(x):
    """
    Исходная функция для последующего интергрирования 
    """
    res = (1+np.sqrt(x))/(x**2)
    return res

def gauss_integrated(a, b):
    """
    Функция получения интеграла по методу Гаусса 
    """
    # 1. запросим порядок формулы и точность 
    n = int( input('Введите порядок формулы (количество узлов от 1 до 6): ') )
    delta = float( input('Введите точность расчета (десятичная дробь): ') )
    
    # 2. определим условие, при котором n не может быть меньше единицы и больше пяти
    assert n>=1 and n<=5, 'Определите n от 1 до 6'
    
    # 3. определим максимаьное количество итераций удвоения интервалов 
    max_iter = 100 
    
   # 4. определим словарь с коэффициентами t:
    ...
    
    # 6. определим функцию расчета интеграла
    def gauss(n):
        ...
        
        # 6.4. определим переменную для параметра j 
        # ДАННЫЙ ПАРАМЕТР НЕОБХОДИМО УДАИВАТЬ ДЛЯ ТОЧНОСТИ
        j_els = n-1
    
        # 6.5. Рассчитаем интеграл с параметром j
        ...

        # 6.5.2. получим значение интеграла по формуле    
        s_j = ( ((b-a)/(2*(j_els+1))) * sum_outside )
        
        return s_j
    
    # 7. создадим две переменных: одна с количеством интервалов n, другая - с (n+1)
    integ_1 = gauss(n)
    n += 1
    integ_2 = gauss(n)

    # 8. применим критерий точности вычисления 
    err_gauss = abs((integ_2 - integ_1)/integ_2)

    # 9. с помощью цикла добьемся требуемой точности расчета 
    while err_gauss > delta:
        if i <= max_iter:
            i += 1
            integ_1 = integ_2
            j_els *= 2
            integ_2 = gauss()
            err_gauss = abs((integ_2 - integ_1)/integ_2)
            # корректировка точности
            if err_gauss <= delta:
                break
        else:
            print('Достигнуто максимальное количество итераций')
            break
   
    # 10. Выведем результаты
    print('Интеграл по методу Гаусса: ', integ_2)
    print('Итоговое количество интервалов: ', j_els)
```

Comment: Сделайте `j_els` аргументом функции `gauss`. В Питоне данные в функцию могут попасть только двумя способами: или как параметры или как элементы замыкания. Второе сложно и тут не нужно. А первое просто и понятно: нужна переменная? Передаём параметром.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy вроде бы еще через глобальную переменную, атрибут функции и yield (`x =  yield`) могут попасть

Comment: @АлексейР, глобальные переменные - часть замыкания. Что такое `x = yield` не знаю.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy https://www.bestprog.net/en/2021/12/03/python-generator-functions-yield-statement-next-iter-send-methods/#q06

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy вопрос, являются ли глобальные переменные элементами замыкания - дискуссионный. В источниках они часто противопоставляются  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535994/why-are-closures-better-than-global-variables-for-preserving-variables

Comment: @АлексейР, глобальные переменные - особенная часть замыкания. В некоторых языках замыкание целиком состоит из глобальных переменных, в некоторых языках в замыкание добавляются символы из объемлющих лексических контекстов. Вспомнил, `x = yield` - конструкция JavaScript. Новую переменную она не вводит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если задача заключается в том, чтобы сохранять значение локальной переменной между вызовами функции, то для этого может подойти [атрибут функции](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/opredelenie-funktsij-python/funktsii-mogut-imet-atributy/):

```
def outer_fun():
    def inner_fun(n):
        if inner_fun.j_els is None:
            inner_fun.j_els = n - 1
        inner_fun.j_els *= 2
        print(f'j_els = {inner_fun.j_els}')
        return inner_fun.j_els

    inner_fun.j_els = None      # здесь явно меняем
    while inner_fun(3) < 100:   # здесь сохраняем значение между вызовами функции
        pass
    inner_fun.j_els = 100500    # здесь опять явно меняем 
    inner_fun(0)

outer_fun()
```

```
j_els = 4
j_els = 8
j_els = 16
j_els = 32
j_els = 64
j_els = 128
j_els = 201000
```